# ng-model for the custom directive Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Problem Question,

I have a custom datepicker directive and want to link ng-model to it in the view.

```
<div my-date-picker ng-model="date">
     {{date}}
</div>
```

the ng-model {{date}} does not display can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong

I have plunker created http://plnkr.co/edit/bWpNITdjBLZJO1p221xe?p=preview.

Comment: What is your question? What's not working, what are you expecting can you give a bit more background?

Comment: one thing I notice is that in your template you are binding:  ng-model="Date" in whereas in your code you are calling it "date" also where are you setting $scope.date initially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `<div my-date-picker ng-model="date">` datepicker dirctive

that means  your going to replace inside of this div, by the template in the directive so your `{{ Date }}` is no longer there its replaced by the template.

if u put `{{ Date }}` outside of the div it will work

and note that model is not `date` it should be `Date` coz the model name of the input is `Date` check the directive template

```
template: '<input class="dateInput" is-open="openthis.isOpened" type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="Date" ng-required="true" />'
```

working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pd7Hjir9rN78jqawcVkt?p=preview)

---

**OR** you can add `{{ Date }}` to the directive template

```
 template: '<input class="dateInput" is-open="openthis.isOpened" type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="Date" ng-required="true" />' +
        '<span ng-click="open($event)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar calImage"></span>'+
        '<h2>{{ Date }}</h2>',
```

Comment: currently my date is coming but with time, I am after shortDate. How would I filter this on ng-model? I need on ng-model as I will be passing this as a parameter. Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: use a date filter `{{ Date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}`

Comment: I want to filter on ng-model="Date | date: "short" (this does not work) as this date will be passed to my controller and then to API.

Comment: filter the date inside the controller just before passing it into the API. ex: `$filter('date')(Date , "dd-MM-yyyy");` , dont forget to inject the $filter dependency in your controller

Comment: It does not work :( can you please have a look at my updated plunker? and help me please? http://plnkr.co/edit/bWpNITdjBLZJO1p221xe?p=preview

Comment: :) cheerz. glad to help you :)